# Warum kein Artikel in "Hören Sie Gespräch eins"?

Tags: usage, article

Ich habe in einem Buch gelesen:

> Hören Sie Gespräch eins und notieren Sie die Adresse.

Warum ist hier kein Artikel vor *Gespräch*, aber vor *Adresse*?

Comment: "Listen to dialogue 1 and note the address". Looks like the description of an exercise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Gespräch 1" steht für einen Namen bzw. eine individuelle Bezeichnung, "die Adresse" hingegen für ein allgemeines Objekt.

Ein anderes Beispiel:

> Fragen Sie Herrn XY (Name), ob er Brecht gelesen hat.
>
> Fragen Sie den Herrn (allgemein), ob er mein Buch gelesen hat.

wobei ein vergleichbares Verhältnis zwischen "Brecht" und "mein Buch" besteht.
Es müsste ja im Englischen ebenso funktionieren (das Beispiel von Afzal stammt aus einem Sprachlehrbuch):

> Listen to dialogue no. 1 and put down the address.
>
> Listen to the dialogue and put down the address!

Comment: *call?* It seems that the OP took that from a German book. I'd think *Gespräch* means there *dialog.*

Comment: "Brecht" und "mein Buch" sind jeweils ein zweites Beispiel ;) Könnte man noch hervorheben.

Comment: @ Em1 Danke!  — @ c.p. Maybe, but if anything, numbering phone calls definitely makes more sense to me than numbering dialogs ;-)

Comment: I'd go with "Listen to dialogue [...]".

Comment: But what do you think is the context here? When or why would somebody speak of dialogue 1, dialogue 2 etc.? In a language lab, perhaps, if there is an address involved, but this seems kind of far-fetched to me.

Comment: OP did not explicitly mention it, but my assumption is that this is a task or exercise from some textbook. Aside: in order for someone to get notified when you write a comment, you need to write their name like this: @Bacchus. That person needs to be involved in the question/answer in some way, though. The author of the question/answer will always be informed of any comments.

Comment: The text is taken from a language book. The context is: Listen dialogue 1 and note the address.

Comment: @ Grantwalzer — well, we both didn't do it ;-)

Comment: @ Afzal — Thanks. But it doesn't really matter, I think we all get the point with "call 1", as well.

Comment: @ Grantwalzer — I just wanted to add: I was notified of your comments despite you left out the @. Perhaps this goes automatically when the aswering comment is next in line.